# MySql - Stopping duplicates with a trigger

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to restrict duplicates based on the following criteria:

`start_date = new.start_date and name = new.name`.

**My trigger is**:

```
IF (
     (SELECT start_date_time
       FROM `db1`
       WHERE name = NEW.name) = NEW.start_date_time) THEN
  SET NEW.start_date = NULL;

  END IF
```

Unfortunately, every time I do a mass insert query I get the following error:

**Error**

```
Subquery returns more than 1 row at....
```

Can someone please explain how to resolve this issue?

Comment: In your criteria you use `start_date` but in your trigger you use `start_date_time`. Which is correct?

Comment: Both are columns. I want to update the start_date rather than the start_date_time column if the condition is met.